# Trying to insert into table from temp table - Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values from temp table to another table and it is giving syntax error. I am not sure what I missed here. Error is on select statement

```
INSERT INTO Reimbursement_EBSUtilization (PRR_Id, SD_Id, ServiceMonth, StandardUnits,
                UnitsDelivered, Rate, BHFormName,  LastChgDate, LastChgUserId) 
    SELECT (
        83, serviceid, 2016/03/01, StandardUnits,
        null, Rate, BHFormsName, getdate(), 'vpanaka') 
    FROM
        @temp
```

Comment: Dates need single quotes around them.

Comment: tried that too still getting the same issue

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses wrapping your select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put single quotes around the date and remove the parentheses around all the columns:

```
INSERT INTO Reimbursement_EBSUtilization(PRR_Id, SD_Id, ServiceMonth, 
                                         StandardUnits, UnitsDelivered, Rate, BHFormName, 
                                         LastChgDate, LastChgUserId) 
    select 83, serviceid, '2016-03-01',  -- Hyphens are the ISO 8601 standard
           StandardUnits, null, Rate, BHFormsName,
           getdate(), 'vpanaka'
    from @temp t;
```

I would recommend that you use default values for `LastChgDate` and `LastChgUserId`, so you don't have to set them on input:

```
LastChgDate datetime default getdate(),      -- or `datetime2` if you prefer
LastChgUserId sysname default @@system_user  -- I think this is what you want for the user
```

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses are breaking the SQL. It's not a valid format/pattern.

```
select(
83,
serviceid,
2016/03/01,
StandardUnits,
null,
Rate,
BHFormsName,
getdate(),
'vpanaka') 
from @temp
```

should be

```
select
   83,
   serviceid,
   '2016/03/01',
   StandardUnits,
   null,
   Rate,
   BHFormsName,
   getdate(),
   'vpanaka'
from @temp
```